# What's wrong w/ this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("text1").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.patrat
{
    background: blue;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="patrat">
     <p class="text1">asdasdsad</p>
 </div>
```

This is the code that records my script in WordPress:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_script_method2');

function my_script_method2()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/slider/sample.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

}
```

How can I make this script work?

It's very simple script but unfortunately it does not work and I can not figure out why.

Comment: What, exactly - "does not work"?

Comment: nothing happens when I run the site and clicked on paragraph

Answer (score 1):

change your jquery code to :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".text1").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selector should be `.text1`, please see below:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".text1").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it does not work